# Expression describing standing waves

Tags: waves

In my textbook, it says that a stationary wave is generated upon interference with the incident and the reflected wave. Well, if there is a reflected wave, I suppose that there would be a phase change of 180 degrees. When that happens won't we express the reflected wave as the following?

$$y = A\sin (kx + \omega t + \pi)$$

Assuming that the reflected wave is coming from the opposite end and having a negative amplitude.

Comment: Of course you can. What is the problem?

Comment: @A.Melkani No, you can't.

Comment: Just add $y_1 = A\sin (kx + \omega t)$ to $y_2 = A\sin (kx - \omega t)$.  You can add a phase angle to one of the functions to make a particular value of $x$ a node or an anti node.

Comment: Keep in mind that $\sin (x + \pi) = -\sin(x)$. See: those goofy trig identities they made you (try to) learn are good for something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standing wave is formed when you have a continuous source of disturbance on one end. Consider a string whose one end is fixed and the other end is attached to a source of disturbance.

Let the equation of the wave created by the source of disturbance be:

$$y = A\sin (kx + \omega t)$$

This wave travels through the string and reflects from the fixed end of the string. The reflected wave is traveling in the opposite direction and is also 180 degrees out of phase (reflections from fixed ends of a string are 180 degrees out of phase). Therefore, the equation of the wave is given by:

$$y = A\sin (kx - \omega t + \pi)$$

The reflected wave is NOT the equation of the standing wave. As you might already know, two waves can interfere to form a new wave. The new wave is given by the sum of the two waves.

The equation of the standing wave is given by (for a general case where the phase difference is $\phi$):

$$y = A\sin (kx - \omega t - \phi) + A\sin (kx + \omega t)$$
$$ = 2A \cos(kx + \frac{\phi}{2})\sin(\omega t - \frac{\phi}{2})$$

Comment: Won't the terms in your final expression cancel out?

Comment: I find it, but is not it 2Asin(kx)cos(wt)?

Comment: I have used $A_o$ instead of $2A$.

Comment: I still have a conceptual doubt though. If my incident wave was from the left to the right in the plane of the +y axis and it returned reflected in the -y axis, won't there be a phase change for the reflected wave?

Comment: I am truly sorry again. I pretty much messed up the answer. The wave which interferes with the original wave needn't necessarily be exactly 180 degrees out of phase. It can be any amount out of phase. The phase difference being 0 and 180 is a special case. I will edit the answer and add the solution for the general case.

Comment: I just have one more doubt: Will there be a sign priority while chosing phasa angle? For instance, you have written the incident wave as + wt, whereas if I write in terms of the -wt idea, will I have to use - pi for my phase change at the boundary?Upon trying to do that kind of a calculation, I got the exact negative of the actual answer (that is yours).

Comment: As a 'stationary' wave wouldn't one expect the superposition to eliminate any factor in the result involving time? In other words when a standing wave is observed over all points in space, the superposition does not appear to be changing with time at any point in that space. But your result indeed contains the factor $\omega t$

Comment: @docscience Each point in the stationary wave is in simple harmonic motion. "stationary" means the wave is not traveling. Standing waves do not transfer energy or momentum. Each particle in the string oscillates in its position.

Comment: @V.Karthik Yes. The sign between the $kx$ and $\omega t$ factor gives the direction of the wave. If you multiply the inside term by -1, you will have to use -$\pi$. This has nothing to do with physics, it is just trigonometry.

Comment: If the sign of the $\omega t$ term is same as $kx$, then the direction of motion of the wave is in the -ve x direction. If the signs are different, the direction of motion is along the +ve x direction.